# How to remove page/menu from page title in Joomla 2.5 and 3+ on front page only

Tags: joomla, title, page

I have a Joomla 2.5 website and I would like to remove the page/menu name from appearing in the title so it does not display in Google or the browser tab. Currently the homepage is appending 'HOME' to the page title i.e:

`<title>Example Sitename - Page/Menu Name</title>`

I know that the "Browser Page Title" can be found within "Page Display Options", but if I leave it empty, it uses the Menu Item Title.

Please note that I only want to remove the page/menu name on the front page of site, also the solution should be working for bilingual (or multilingual) websites, that means "My Website - Home" will be "My Website" and other languages will follow the same rule, i.e. "Mon Website - Accueil" will be "Mon Website".

Comment: Does anyone know if this has an option for Joomla 3x TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As George Okello said, you have to notice the First page's Id. Go to Menu Manager and find them out for each language. There must be a different configuration if you have a plugin for multilingual websites.

in my case both ids were 127 and 128. So the solution is to put the following code before the  `<jdoc:include type="head" />`.

```
<?php
  $menuItemId = JRequest::getInt('Itemid');
  if ($menuItemId == 127) : $this->setTitle('Theater of the Deaf of Greece');
  elseif ($menuItemId == 128) : $this->setTitle('Θέατρο Κωφών Ελλάδος');
  endif;
?>
```

Now if you have a multilingual website, all you have to do is to copy the line `elseif ($menuItemId == xx ) : $this->setTitle('xxxx');` and paste it before the `endif;` for as many languages (or pages with unique id's) you wish.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I found until now (Joomla 3.0) is adding the following snippet in your template's index.php file before `<jdoc:include type="head" />`.

The snippet for my page looks like this:

```
<?php
if (!strncmp($this->getTitle(), "Home", 4))
{
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $this->setTitle( $app->getCfg( 'sitename' ) );  
}
?>
```

This basically is a hack that replaces the title if it begins with "Home".

Comment: What about Joomla 2.5.8?...

Comment: Doesn't work for earlier version of Joomla :/

Answer (score 3):

*To do this in **Joomla 2.5** do the following steps:*

- Login to the Joomla backend using your administrator account

  - Click menu manager

    - Click Main Menu

      - Click on Home and take note of the menu ID.

Then add the following code to template's index.php file, before `<jdoc:include type="head" />` (note that in the example below, 101 should be replaced with the actual ID number on your site as mentioned in the steps above.

```
<?php
    $menuItemId = JRequest::getInt('Itemid');
    if ($menuItemId == 101) $this->setTitle('');
?>
```

*If you want a custom title, e.g. My Custom Title, then use:*

- `$this->setTitle('My Custom Title');`

I have not tested this on a multilingual website, but assuming each language has its own home page, you would just test for all home pages, using their unique menu item ids.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I m gonna try it. Is this gonna change the way Google shows the title of my website too?

Comment: It works for a monolingual website. Even though doesn't replies exactly what my question stated, helped me to find the the right answer for the bilingual website.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend installing [AceSEF](http://www.joomace.net/joomla-extensions/acesef-joomla-seo-sef-urls) or [SH404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef) within Joomla. AceSEF is free and does the job while SH404SEF tends to have slightly more features but comes a price. Joomla SEO is ok out of the box but its far from perfect, altering templates is ok but using an extension is far easier and does more SEO than just what you asked.

*These plugins can be installed on all versions of Joomla:*

- Joomla 1.5
- Joomla 2.5
- Joomla 3.0
- Joomla 3.5 and above...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Show Page Heading" is set to No under Page Display Options for the Home menu item. That will hide the title as long as you have also set "Show Title" to Hide under Article options of the same menu item.

Comment: Does not work for me.. my home page is a "category blog" and even if I additionally set "Category Title" to Hide under "Category Options" the page still says "Home - ..."

Comment: @Trev yeaaah, Tarnschaf is right.. If i put show page heading to no, then it removes my h1 tag I have set with the entry "Page Heading" into the page. 
What I need is that my 'Browser title is set to blank and later it won't pick a title from my 'Menu title'..

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $title = $this->getTitle();
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        //$this->setTitle( $title . ' - ' . $app->getCfg( 'sitename' ) );
        $this->setTitle( 'your funky title' );
    ?>
```

It is all in [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_dynamic_page_title)

Try adding `if(str_pos($this->getTitle(), "Part of your home page title")!=false)`

Comment: I have the feeling that you didn't read or understand my question..

Comment: system didn't let edit my commend so I continue here:
I especially wrote: 'I want this omission of browser page title only for the home page.'
Your solution only partially works.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*The Joomla plugin called [Title Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/title-management/3521) can handle this for you. Simply use:*

- `Only show site name on home page: Yes`

Comment: Thanks for informing me about it. Does this affects also how Google shows the website title?